# How do I append a key value pair to an existing hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, append

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to 'inject' key/value pairs to an existing hash in Ruby. I know you can do this with << for arrays, for e.g.

```
arr1 = []
a << "hello"
```

But could I do something similar for a hash? So something like

```
hash1 = {}
hash1 << {"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
```

Basically, I'm trying push key value pairs in a loop based on a condition.

```
# Encoder: This shifts each letter forward by 4 letters and stores it  in a hash called cipher. On reaching the end, it loops back to the first letter
def encoder (shift_by)
alphabet = []
cipher = {}
alphabet =  ("a".."z").to_a
alphabet.each_index do |x|
        if (x+shift_by) <= 25
            cipher = {alphabet[x] => alphabet[x+shift_by]}
        else
            cipher = {alphabet[x] => alphabet[x-(26-shift_by)]} #Need this piece to push additional key value pairs to the already existing cipher hash.
        end
end
```

Sorry for pasting my whole method here. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 3 ways:

> [`.merge(other_hash)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-merge) Returns a new hash containing the contents of other_hash and the contents of hsh.

```
hash = { a: 1 }
puts hash.merge({ b: 2, c: 3 }) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

> [`.merge!(other_hash)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) Adds the contents of other_hash to hsh.

```
hash = { a: 1 }
puts hash.merge!({ b: 2, c: 3 }) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

And most efficient way is to modify existing hash, setting new values directly:

```
hash = { a: 1 }
hash[:b] = 2
hash[:c] = 3
puts hash # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Corresponding Benchmarks for these methods:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.013348)
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.003285)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000918)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) the two hashes together:

```
hash1 = {}
hash1.merge!({"a" => 1, "b" => 2})
```